How to find the nearest point using RegionNearest for this case?
Consider the following region:
reg = BooleanRegion[#1 &&  ! #2 & , {Parallelepiped[{-3.24, -2.415, 
      9.2}, 
         {{6.48, 0, 0}, {0, 4.83, 0}, {0, 0, 0.20000000000000004}}], 
       Cylinder[{{0., 0., 9.2}, {0., 0., 9.4}}, 0.09]}];

I am trying to find the nearest point to it by using RegionNearest:
RegionNearest[reg, {0, 0, 0}]

It returns TerminatedEvaluation[RecursionLimit]. If I set $RecursionLimit = Infinity, it returns something wrong:
{-2.53548*10^-27,2.94122*10^-20,9.2}

whereas it must be any point at the edge of the cylinder. Since reg is just one of the examples of various geometries, I must use RegionNearest or something like this to keep generality, and I cannot simply find it manually.
Could you please tell me how to force it to work?
Mathematica 13.2@Windows 11.

To get a numeric result, Maybe you can use DiscretizeRegion.
RegionNearest[
 DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.00001], {0, 0, 0}]

(*{0.0410127, 0.0613983, 9.2}*)

Update
For better performance using this method, maybe we can use the function in ToElementMesh in FEM:
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]
RegionNearest[MeshRegion[mesh], {0, 0, 0}]

(*{0.0835379, 0.0316817, 9.2}*)


Rationalize your region
reg = BooleanRegion[#1 && ! #2 &, {Apply[Parallelepiped, 
     Rationalize[{{-3.24, -2.415, 
        9.2}, {{6.48, 0, 0}, {0, 4.83, 0}, {0, 0, 
         0.20000000000000004}}}, 0]], 
    Apply[Cylinder, 
     Rationalize[{{{0., 0., 9.2}, {0., 0., 9.4}}, 0.09}, 0]]}];

RegionNearest[reg, {0, 0, 0}]
(*{-(9/100), 0, 46/5}*)

